# /etc/resolv.conf" E166: Can't open linked file for writing

Tags: resolv.conf, resolvconf

Unable to update `resolv.conf` file.

```
/etc/resolv.conf" E166: Can't open linked file for writing
```

Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Where or why did you get that error message?  If it is in `vim` (which you haven't specified) E166 can be found in http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html

Comment: Thanks for reply! i managed to to resolve issue the filesystem was mount with ro and user was not with root permission.

Answer (score 6):

This is an assumption that you're asking about a `vim` error message (you didn't specify where you got the error message).

Vim documentation reports E166 as

***E166*  Can't open linked file for writing**

> You are trying to write to a file which can't be overwritten, and the
>   file is a link (either a hard link or a symbolic link).  Writing might
>   still be possible if the directory that contains the link or the file
>   is writable, but Vim now doesn't know if you want to delete the link
>   and write the file in its place, or if you want to delete the file
>   itself and write the new file in its place.  If you really want to
>   write the file under this name, you have to manually delete the link
>   or the file, or change the permissions so that Vim can overwrite.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   stat /etc/resolv.conf 
  File: /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
  Size: 39          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 130757      Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-09-03 12:34:28.189468370 +1000
Modify: 2017-11-16 12:32:04.777265492 +1100
Change: 2017-11-16 12:32:04.777265492 +1100
```

A `stat` of my /etc/resolv.conf confirms the file is a link.

*I can happily write to that file (using `sudo`) so you have an issue beyond what you've provided.*

Comment: In my case it links to `./resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. Either way,
how do I fix the problem? The file and folder it links to do not exist. I can not `cd ../run/resolvconf/`. Says no such file or directory...

Comment: `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` exists on my current system (likely the same box I was using with the answer; only it's running *impish* now where it would have been *cosmic* then). If you used "../run" in a command it would have been interpreted as a *relative location* (ie. relative to $PWD) which is different to the intention of the command output.  You're likely best asking a new question though,

Answer (score 6):

if `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link, you won't be able to write it. If you want to overwrite the content in the file, remove the file and then create a new fi

1. Remove symbolic link

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

2. Write to new file. E.g.

```bsh
sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8"  > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case it worked when I used `sudo` while opening `resolv.conf` file through vi. If file is not already present then it creates one.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: using sudo works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. The filesystem was mounted with `ro` (read only) and the user was not with root permission.